# windbg dds - unable to get source where memory allocated

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, windbg

I'm following the directions on windbg.info to try and find the source corresponding to a memory allocation/leak in my program.  I set up a test case with leaky code to try and demonstrate this.  I can get part of the way there, but not able to see actual source.

The C++ code in question is a debug build (optimization turned off, etc).   Called multiple times.

```
class test
{
public:
    int Allocate() 
    {
        pai = new int[128];
        pasz = new char[128];
    } 

private:
    int * pai = nullptr;
    char * pasz = nullptr;
};
```

I'm following the directions on windbg.info (shortened):

> 1. To get source information you must additionally enable page heap in step 1 (gflags.exe /i MyApp.exe +ust +hpa)
>      ...
> 2. Do a !heap -flt s [Size]. [Size]=AllocSize determined previously. This command will list down all blocks with that particular size.
> 3. Do a !heap -p -a [UserAddr] to get the stack trace from where you have allocated that much bytes. Use the [UserAddr] that you got in previous step
> 4. Do a dt ntdll!_DPH_HEAP_BLOCK StackTrace [MyHeapBlockAddr], where [MyHeapBlockAddr] is the DPH_HEAP_BLOCK address retrieved in step 3.
> 5. Do a dds [StackTrace]", where [StackTrace] is the value retrieved in previous step.
>      Note that dds will dump the stack with source information included.

I do have all symbols loaded correctly:

```
00007ff7`b1400000 00007ff7`b142b000   ConsoleApplication1 C (private pdb symbols)  c:\...
00007ff8`37ae0000 00007ff8`37c9e000   ucrtbased   (private pdb symbols)  c:\...
00007ff8`39d20000 00007ff8`39e16000   MSVCP140D   (private pdb symbols)  c:\...
00007ff8`40e30000 00007ff8`40e9e000   verifier   (private pdb symbols)  c:\...
00007ff8`40ec0000 00007ff8`40ee2000   VCRUNTIME140D   (private pdb symbols) c:\...
00007ff8`6a410000 00007ff8`6a62d000   KERNELBASE   (private pdb symbols) c:\...
00007ff8`6b4c0000 00007ff8`6b56c000   KERNEL32   (private pdb symbols) c:\...
00007ff8`6d9e0000 00007ff8`6dbb1000   ntdll      (private pdb symbols)  c:\...
```

I do see a 'good' stack that shows the call to test::Allocate:

```
0:004> !heap -flt s 2034
_DPH_HEAP_ROOT @ 272d60e1000
Freed and decommitted blocks
  DPH_HEAP_BLOCK : VirtAddr VirtSize
Busy allocations
  DPH_HEAP_BLOCK : UserAddr  UserSize - VirtAddr VirtSize
    00000272d60ecf70 : 00000272d6467fc0 0000000000002034 - 00000272d6467000 0000000000004000

0:004> !heap -p -a  00000272d6467fc0 
address 00000272d6467fc0 found in
_DPH_HEAP_ROOT @ 272d60e1000
in busy allocation (  DPH_HEAP_BLOCK:         UserAddr         UserSize -         VirtAddr         VirtSize)
                         272d60ecf70:      272d6467fc0             2034 -      272d6467000             4000
...
00007ff7b14142a8 ConsoleApplication1!test::Allocate+0x0000000000000048
00007ff7b141495a ConsoleApplication1!main+0x000000000000008a
...
```

I thought I might be able to now get the source of this memory allocation:

```
0:004> dt ntdll!_DPH_HEAP_BLOCK StackTrace 00000272d60ecf70 
+0x060 StackTrace : 0x00000272`d2f106d0 _RTL_TRACE_BLOCK

0:004> dds  0x00000272`d2f106d0 
00000272`d2f106d0  00000000
00000272`d2f106d4  00000000
00000272`d2f106d8  00008804
...
```

No source even though I do have 'source file path' set.  I have not found any examples of what a successful case looks like.  Have I done something wrong in the environment set up, or the commands?

windbg version: 6.12.0002.633 AMD64.  x64 test executable.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - the 'Enable page heap' step came right from windbg.info.  http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#20_memory_heap.  Is that not authoritative, or is it out of date?

Comment: @ThomasWeller 'dps' did the trick.  If you want to post a solution, I'll be happy to accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dds` is the command for **d**ump **D**WORD and interpret as **s**tack. This may work for 32 bit applications.

Your application is a 64 bit application. I can see this from addresses like `00007ff7'b1400000` which contain a backtick. So you should use `dqs` (dump quad words and interpret as stack).

Even better is `dps` (dump pointer size and interpret as stack), since it will use 32 or 64 bit depending on the architecture of your application.